# Insert a row that contains relational data?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

This is a simplified version but... a user can submit the form which contains their name and qualification.

I have two tables - users and qualifications. A user has many qualifications. A qualification has one user.

I save like so:

```
$user = new User;
$user->first_name = 'Derek';

$qualification = new Qualification;
$qualification->qualification = 'History Degree';

DB::transaction(function() use ($user, $qualification) {
   $user->save();
   User::find($user->id)->qualifications()->save($qualification);
});
```

My questions are:

Is this the correct way to insert a row to a table and it's relationship? Is there a better way?

And my 2nd question...this line:

```
User::find($user->id)->qualifications()->save($qualification);
```

This may be a bit crazy but I just would like this explaining to me, the $user->id gets the id of the previously inserted row, if two people were to insert at the same time, how would I be sure that it would get the correct id? As in, user A saves, then user B saves, then the first User::find bit runs for user A but this would find user B's id. Is this where the transaction comes in?

Comment: `$user->id` gets the id from the `$user` object, not the id of the previously inserted row.

Comment: User A and user B will have their own _Request Cycles_ in which `$user` variable for user A will have its own `id` property. There is no way `$qualification` for user A's `$user` will be attached to user B's `$user` as far as I understand PHP and Laravel.

Answer (score -1):

Before you save the user by doing this:

```
user->save();
```

I think you should first save the "qualification" to that user.  As long as your code functions as you currently have it, I would think this would do the trick:

```
$user->qualifications()->save($qualification);
```

and then do

```
user->save();
```

If you can get it to work in that order, you'll never have to worry about obtaining the wrong user ID and switching the qualifications on the wrong user, if they were to enter their information at approximately the same time.

Comment: Thanks but this will not work. How would you be able to insert the relationship on qualifications if you do not know the id it belongs to?

Comment: Do you think a one-to-many relationship would work?  Are you familiar with that feature of Laravel?

Comment: This code does not work. And as my question stated it is a one to may relationship.

Comment: Make sure you have the one-to-many code set up correctly in your migrations and tables, and the basic one-to-many functions in your Models set up correctly.  I can walk you through that if you would like.  If you've got all that set up correctly, I think you need this:     $qualification->user()->associate(Auth::user());     This way, the qualification will always get matched with the user who is logged in that create the qualification in question.